# SVN and NetBeans 8 can't import into subversion repository

Tags: php, svn, netbeans

When I select my project and right-click, choosing Versioning -> Import into Subversion repository...

I get this message:

> Import is not allowed because of too many selected roots

There are no SVN folders locally.  How do I fix this?

Comment: How did you create your project? Are there existing `.svn` dirs in any of the folders? Are there existing `nbproject` dirs in any of them?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but it is a PHP project, probably from Remote Source.  There are no SVN folders locally.

Comment: Well Ive never see that error before so i think its something to do with Netbeans and how its interpreting the project structure or that your projects may not have actually been selected, or that you had multiple projects selected.

Comment: Also FYI i always do my `svn import` or my `git clone`/`git init` from the CLI or with a client outside NetBeans (or Eclipse when i use that IDE) then I just open the project afterwards and do my setup. Not a solution for you, just an alternate workflow.

Comment: Formatting; included notes from comments

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was right-clicking on the "Project" to get the SVN options.  If I right-click on the "Source Files" the SVN import isn't available, but selecting the "Source Files" and then going to the menu: Team->Subversion->Import into repository...  It works!

Thanks prodigitalson for all your help!